# os.popen doesn't work after compiler with pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x

The following line is what I'm using to open the file in python, and this action called by a button(tkinter).

```
os.popen(r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe" %s' %filename)
```

My development environment is Python3.7 + spyder 3.3.1 + windows 7 + latest version pyinstaller.

The issue is that this line can work well in spyder, but after compiler.

```
pyinstaller -F -w --onefile --icon=icon.ico ./DMS.py
```

I used this command to compile the Python script. When I click the button which I mentioned above, there is no any action be executed and no any error message pop up. I'm sure the application didn't hang on or crush.

When I try the following command to check what message on console.

```
pyinstaller -F DMS.py
```

The miracle happen, the PDF file can be opened without problem, and there is no any error message show on the console.

Does anyone know what things happen? and any suggestion for this case if show the console front of end user is not an option.

Many thanks.